# Chikka SMS API Message Receiver URL not working

Tags: php, api, laravel, sms-gateway

The Message Receiver URL of the API is not reading/passing any data into the URL that I have used, no actions or logs are being triggered into my server (since if the URL is called by the Message Receiver in the API a row will be inserted into of the tables in my database).

Any help or suggestions on how can I make the Message Receiver URL work?

```
    $message_type = $_POST["message_type"];

    if (strtoupper($message_type) == "INCOMING")
    {
        $message = 'Sample';
        $mobile_number = $_POST["mobile_number"];
        $shortcode = $_POST["shortcode"];
        // $timestamp = $_POST["timestamp"];
        // $request_id = $_POST["request_id"];

        $content = 'Accepted';
        $status = 200;

        DB::table('action_history_label')->insert(['action_id' => 'SDSDS', 'action_label' => 'New Receive']);

        $this->data['client_id']        = 'CLIENT_ID';
        $this->data['secret_key']       = 'SECRET_KEY';
        $this->data['short_code']       = 'SHORTCODE';
        $chikkaAPI = new ChikkaSMS($this->data['client_id'],$this->data['secret_key'],$this->data['short_code']);
        $response = $chikkaAPI->sendText(md5(date('YmdHms').uniqid(rand(), true)), $mobile_number, 'REPLY FVCK!');

        return response()->json(['status' => $status, 'message' => $content]);
    }
    else
    {
        $content = 'Error';
        $status = 500;
        return response()->json(['status' => $status, 'message' => $content]);
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Without any code, how should anybody help you here?

Comment: Sorry first time posting here